# How to specify build-specific directory in Gradle?

Tags: android, qt, android-gradle-plugin

When one creates an Android Studio project, the build layout structure is something as follows:

```
src
  main
    java
      ...
    res
      ...
  release
    ...
  debug
    ...
```

For each build such as release, debug, etc., you can create a sibling directory to `main` and add build-specific files.

The project I am working on has a different layout. This project is created by Qt Creator toolkit. The root directory (the one that has `build.gradle`file) itself has `src` and `res` directories. There is no `main` directory. Gradle build works fine. However, I am confused on how to extend it with build-specific files. Where do I create build-specific directories such as `release` and `beta?` How does gradle determine which directory to use for the main build as well as any other specific builds? Regards.

Edit - I have added the following based on the user request:

My `build.gradle` file is nothing special. I have extended it a bit to deal with various build types we have:

```
buildTypes {
    debug {
        applicationIdSuffix ".debug"
        debuggable true
    }
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
    }
    beta {
        applicationIdSuffix ".beta"
        debuggable true
    }
    alpha {
        applicationIdSuffix ".alpha"
        debuggable true
     }
```

Comment: Please post your `build.gradle` file(s).

Comment: Thank you for your help. I have added a part of build.gradle to my original post.

Comment: And since you did not post the relevant portions of `build.gradle`, I cannot help you very much. Your `build.gradle` contains the rules that is mapping the directories in your actual project to the roles for the build process. You would need to do the same sort of mapping for any other sourcesets, such as ones for your build types.